# typeahead empty template not working

Tags: typeahead.js

I am setting up typeahead like so:

```
       $this.typeahead({ 
            prefetch: $this.data('url-prefetch'), 
            templates: { 
                empty: 'No matching files found' 
            } 
        })
```

The prefetch is working fine but the empty template is not displayed when there are no matches.

Comment: What you have looks fine. See this as an example http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/u4fq85bj/. Do you get any errors in your browser debug console?

Comment: Which typeahead.js version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

To whoever comes across this issue:

"Empty" template will not show up if you have **{async:true}** in the options

```
$this.typeahead({
  async: false,
  prefetch: $this.data('url-prefetch'), 
  templates: { 
    empty: 'No matching files found' 
  } 
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But after see the repo, I use another suggestion library.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamental changes have been made in Typeahead.js v0.10.x. Examining your code, it looks like you're targeting Typeahead v0.9.x, so make sure you load this older version, or things won't work.

I suggest you update your code to support v0.10.x, here is a migration guide:
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/migration/0.10.0.md